# Event not being triggered in Python

Tags: python

When I left click on the matplotlib figure, my program will draw a line from [0,0] to the position I clicked. On right click, the program is suppose to draw a line from [0,0] to [100,100] regardless of where I clicked. Yet my program does not do this.

here is my code

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np





fig, ax = plt.subplots()

arrowflag=False

def onclick(event):
    global arrowflag, Xf, Yf
    

    if event.button == 1:
        plt.xlim(0,10)
        plt.ylim(0,10)
        if arrowflag==True:
            plt.cla()
        arrowflag=True
        plt.arrow(0,0,event.xdata,event.ydata)
        plt.draw()
        plt.xlim(0,10)
        plt.ylim(0,10)
        
    else: 
        plt.cla()
        
        x=np.empty(10000)
        y=np.empty(10000)
        
        x[0]=0
        y[0]=0
        
        x[1]=100#event.xdata
        y[1]=100#event.ydata
        
        Xf=x[:1]
        Yf=y[:1]
        
        plt.plot(Xf,Yf)
        plt.show()
    
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,10)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will draw a line from 0,0 to the point you clicked on left click, and 0,0 to 100,100 on left click:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def onclick(event):
    plt.cla()
    plt.xlim(0,10)
    plt.ylim(0,10)

    if event.button == 1:
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    else: 
        x, y = 100, 100
    
    plt.arrow(0, 0, x, y)
    plt.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.show()
```

There are some extraneous imports/variables I removed